# Clip won't stop in Java after reopening panel

Tags: java, audio, jpanel, java-audio

I am writing a music player that can be played in background while users do their thing. The problem is when I exit the music player panel into other panel, the music can't be stopped anymore.

Here is my code

```
    JButton btnAddMusic = new JButton("add music");
    btnAddMusic.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            returnValue=browser.showOpenDialog(main);
            
            if(returnValue==browser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                selectedFile=browser.getSelectedFile();
                String filepath=selectedFile.toString();
                String filename=selectedFile.getName();
                main.getController().storeMusic(filename, filepath);
                populateJComboBox();
            }
        }
    });
    btnAddMusic.setBounds(15, 187, 115, 29);
    add(btnAddMusic);
    JButton btnlogout = new JButton("");
    btnlogout.setFont(new Font("Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold", Font.PLAIN, 19));
    btnlogout.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
    Image aimg= new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/logot.png")).getImage();
    Image aImage = aimg.getScaledInstance(55, 55, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);

    btnlogout.setIcon(new ImageIcon(aImage));
    btnlogout.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            main.showRegisterPanel();
        }
    });
    btnlogout.setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Button.foreground"));
    btnlogout.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    btnlogout.setOpaque(true);
    btnlogout.setBorderPainted(false);
    btnlogout.setBounds(411, 0, 64, 53);
    add(btnlogout);
    
    JLabel icon = new JLabel("");
    icon.setBounds(15, 16, 93, 81);
    Image img= new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/tplogo.png")).getImage();
    Image newImage = img.getScaledInstance(70, 70, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    icon.setIcon(new ImageIcon(newImage));
    add(icon);
    
    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Music Player");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(155, 29, 276, 53);
    add(lblNewLabel);

    this.btnhome = new JButton("");
    btnhome.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            check();
        }
    });
    btnhome.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    btnhome.setBounds(180, 232, 75, 63);
    Image home= new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/home.png")).getImage();
    Image ahome = home.getScaledInstance(55, 55, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    btnhome.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ahome));
    btnhome.setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Button.foreground"));
    btnhome.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    btnhome.setOpaque(true);
    btnhome.setBorderPainted(false);

    add(btnhome);


    JButton btnPlay = new JButton("play");
    btnPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            
            
            for(int i=0;i<1024;i++){
            try{
                
                if(comboBox.getSelectedIndex()==i){
                    
                    sound=new File(music[comboBox.getSelectedIndex()]);
                    ais=AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound);
                    clip=AudioSystem.getClip();
                    clip.open(ais);
                    clip.start();
                    
                }
                
                
                
            }catch(Exception e){
                
            }
            
        }
        }});
    
    btnPlay.setBounds(170, 187, 115, 29);
    add(btnPlay);
    
    JButton btnStop = new JButton("stop");
    btnStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
            
            clip.stop();
            
            
        }
    });
    btnStop.setBounds(320, 187, 115, 29);
    add(btnStop);
    browser.setFileFilter(filter);
    this.comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.setBounds(77, 111, 262, 26);
    add(comboBox);
    populateJComboBox();
    
}
private void populateJComboBox() {
    this.mu = this.main.getController().getAllMusic(); //get hardcoded cluster details
    DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    for(int i = 0; i<mu.length; i++) // for loop to add the cluster details into the comboBox model
    {   
        Music clu = mu[i];
        model.addElement(clu.getMname());
        music[i]=clu.getMc();
    }
    this.comboBox.setModel(model); //setting the comboBox model with the model with cluster details added
}
private void check(){
this.user = this.main.getController().getAllUsers();
for(int i = 0; i<user.length;i++)
{

    User use = user[i];
    String aa = use.getType(); 
    if(aa=="Student"){
        main.showSthomepanel();
    }
    else if(aa=="Staff"){
        main.showshomePanel();
    }
    else{
        btnhome.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

The initialise is done, but I can't post because of this weird code system.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by the focus being taken away from the panel. The easiest way to fix this is to use a JWindow instead of a JPanel.

Comment: I wish to but the School I attending forces us to use JPanel so I got to use it, anyways thanks for the suggestion =.

Comment: Oh sorry. Good luck